# IBM Websphere 7, support for JAX-WS Service 2.2, it´s possible?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, jax-ws

I have a Java EE application that uses JAX-WS 2.2 and I have to deploy it on WebSphere Application Server 7, but it seems that this version of WAS supports just up to JAX-WS 2.1.

Is there any way of enabling JAX-WS 2.2 on WAS 7? Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible, but I'd open a PMR with your rep just in case. Or upgrade to WAS8...

Answer (score 2):

At fix pack 7 for WAS 7 (7.0.0.7), configuration options were added to disable IBM provided JAX-WS engine that ships with product, and configure a third party JAX-WS engine. You may see details about this fix at [PK93756: ENABLE USE OF THIRD PARTY JAX-WS WEB SERVICES ENGINE IN WEBSPHERE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK93756)

So you shall be able to configure JAX-WS 2.2 implementation of your choice. You may find information on how to configure your server to disable IBM provided JAX-WS engine, and then configure your own implementation at [DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1001_thaker/1001_thaker.html) and WAS 7 [Infocenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/fep/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html).